# Uploading xml with Monotouch fails on the device

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, webclient

I am trying to send an XML via web client on Monotouch. Although everything is working on the iOS simulator I get an exception when the app is running on the device. Here is the code.

```
try
{
   Byte[] sendData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someXML) ;
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   Byte[] forResp;
   client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","text/xml");

   bresp = wc.UploadData(URL, sendData);
   string resp = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(forResp);
   XmlDocument xresp = new XmlDocument();
   xresp.LoadXml(resp);
   return xresp;
}
catch
{
    // error
}
```

I tried the WebClient because I had the same issue with the HttpWebRequest.

Exception:

```
The request timed out
System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00065] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:830 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:836 
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:1433 
  at System.Net.WebClient.ReadAll (System.Net.WebRequest request, System.Object userToken) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:866 
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataCore (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.Byte[] data, System.Object userToken) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:462 
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadData (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.Byte[] data) [0x00035] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:441
```

Comment: what's the exception? type, message, stacktrace?

Comment: I am having a timeout only on the device

Comment: Please edit the question and provide the full exception and stack trace. This is **very** helpful in many cases. Also make sure your device can access the URL you are using to upload (e.g. airplane mode, proxy, self-signed certificates...).

Comment: Just edited the question. I can't understand why I get this exception only on the device and not on the simulator

Comment: And the device has access to the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace tells us that the timeout occurs when `WebClient` tries to get a response from the server (and not when uploading the data to the server). That means access to the server is not the issue (and why stacktraces are very useful ;-)

The next steps depends if you have control, or not, of the server. If you control the server then check it's logs to find the request and see how it was handled. If possible also ensure you received/decoded the data identically between the simulator and device.

If you do not control the server then it's harder to know what's going on inside it. E.g. maybe it did not like the request (i.e. the server code can decide not to answer based on any condition, including the user-agent).

In such case using a tool, like `wireshark`, is often your best bet. Compare the session from the iOS simulator and from the device.

- Is the request identical ? e.g. the data you uploaded could be different due to something else;
- Is the server answering for the device ? with the same status code ? in the same time frame ?

If everything is identical then you might have found a bug. Please report it (along with the above informations and files) to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Otherwise you should have more precise clues to debug the issue and/or update the question to be more specific :-)

Comment: I'll test it as soon as I get my hands on the server. Thanks poupou

Comment: you were right. there was a problem with the ipaddress of the device.

Comment: you were right. I had a problem with the devices ipaddress. Solved it with this http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Can-t-determine-IP-address-on-iPhone-device-td3891425.html